# How do I make images resize to fit inside a certain thumbnail width/height?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a basic image preview box, where you see a large image on the left, and a set of small images as thumbnails on the right.

I need the thumbnails to never exceed a certain width/height, so that they stay in a neat order for viewing pleasure.

What I tried: I learned about max-width and max-height... as you can see in my code below, I've tried both of those, but despite specifically setting a max height and width they still expand and make the thumbnails awkward sizes.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

The problem:

http://puu.sh/2VfR6.png

The HTML:

```
<div class="pictureBoxContainer">
    <div class="pictureBox">
        <div class="pBoxLeftColumn">
            <?php
                echo "<div class='pBoxLargeImageContainer'>";
                echo "<img src='$pictureLinks[0]' alt='Primary Image' class='pBoxLargeImage'>";
                echo "</div>";
            ?>
        </div>
        <div class="pBoxRightColumn">
            <?php
            foreach ($pictureLinks as $picture) 
            {
                echo "<div class='pBoxThumbnailContainer'>";
                echo "<img src='$picture' alt='Thumbnail' class='pBoxThumbnail'>";
                echo "</div>";
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.pictureBoxContainer {
    margin-top: 300px;
    padding: 12px;
    clear:left;
    clear:right;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #F7D961;
    border-radius: 12px;
    max-height: 600px;
}

.pictureBox {
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 12px;
    width: 97%;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 12px;
}

.pBoxLeftColumn {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    min-width: 49.99%;
    max-width: 49.99%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.pBoxRightColumn {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    min-width: 49.99%;
    max-width: 49.99%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.pBoxSmallImageContainer {
    max-height: 20%;
    max-width: 20%;
    float: left;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 3px;
    background-color: #F7D961;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

.pBoxSmallImage {
    padding-top: 2px;
}

.pBoxLargeImageContainer {
    width: 100%;
}

.pBoxLargeImage {
    border-radius: 6px;
    min-width: 450px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set the `max-width` and `max-height` on the wrong element.  Set them on `.pBoxThumbnail` instead.

Comment: I updated my code above to reflect my new CSS changes, and this is the result: http://puu.sh/2VgpB.png --- obviously I'm missing something, mind going into a bit more detail?